# Date parsing of character vector ("Month-Year")

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm trying to parse a vector `tsl` into a date class.

```
tsl <- c("Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", "Dec-2011", 
"Dec-2011")
```

I read the documentation of `as.Date` and I thought that `as.Date(tsl, "%b-Y")` should do the job, but it returns NAs.

I've also tried the following:

```
as.Date(tsl, "bbb-YYYY")
as.Date(tsl, "by")
```

Then I tried using `lubridate` but this didn't work either:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(tsl, "%b-%y")
```

Running `Sys.getlocale()` returns:

> "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: `Date` objects are representations of calendar days as integers, and "Dec-2011" is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with year-month-day dates, here is a solution:

```
as.Date(gsub("^", "01-", tsl), format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

I added on the first of the month using `gsub`.